# Thread Synchronization Behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1,"Thread 1:");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1,"Thread 2:");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    String s1 = "Hello World";
    String s2 = "Hello New World";
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(s1)
        {
            for(int i =0;i<3;++i)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+s1);

        }
        synchronized(s2)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+s2);
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thread 1:Hello World
Thread 1:Hello World
Thread 1:Hello World
Thread 1:Hello New World
Thread 2:Hello World
Thread 1:Hello New World
Thread 2:Hello World
Thread 1:Hello New World
Thread 2:Hello World
Thread 2:Hello New World
Thread 2:Hello New World
Thread 2:Hello New World
```

Why can't `Thread2` execute the second synchronized block in the `run()` method when `Thread1` is executing the first synchronized block even though lock objects are different.Does `Thread2`'s execution wait at the first synchronized block till `Thread1` leaves that block??

If so how to make both synchronized blocks run concurrently??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Thread2's execution wait at the first synchronized block till Thread1 leaves that block??

Yes that's the idea - thread2 executes the blocks one after the other. If it is blocked and can't enter the first one, it will wait there until the `s1` lock becomes available.

> If so how to make both synchronized blocks run concurrently??

You would need to split them in two different runnables and use one thread for each.

Comment: Cool..I thought that the Thread2's execution will skip the the block that is locked

Answer (score 3):

Because within the run method statements are executed in sequentially not parallely.

So who ever Thread 1 or Thread 2 acquire the lock of s1 other will wait untill it is released.

Answer (score 3):

The two blocks are one after the other, which means that Thread 2 has to go though block 1 before going through block 2

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't Thread2 execute the second synchronized block in the run()
>   method when Thread1 is executing the first synchronized block

Code is executed line by line, The execution doesnt jump to next block and Thread 2 waits for Thread 1 to leave the 1st Synchronized block.

> Does Thread2's execution wait at the first synchronized block till
>   Thread1 leaves that block

Yes.

> If so how to make both synchronized blocks run concurrently??

So keep them In seperate Runnable Instances. and Not one after the other in a Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply the compiler execute the code i.e. compiler execute code in sequence the way they are written. thread 2 cannot skip first block of code. it will first execute first block then others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of getting them both to run concurrently. Note that not only have I put each loop in a separate thread but I have reduced the scope of the synchronization to just the print.

```
public class Test {
  static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    final String s1 = " Hello World - ";
    final String s2 = " Hello New World - ";
    static final int n = 10;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Two loops in two threads.
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // Scope reduced.
            synchronized (s1) {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + s1 + i);
            }
          }
        }
      }, Thread.currentThread().getName() + "(a)").start();
      // Two loops in two threads.
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // Scope reduced.
            synchronized (s2) {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + s2 + i);
            }
          }
        }
      }, Thread.currentThread().getName() + "(b)").start();
    }
  }

  public void test() {
    MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, "Thread 1:");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r1, "Thread 2:");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ThreadExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable15756 r1 = new MyRunnable15756();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1,"Thread 1:");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r1,"Thread 2:");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}

class MyRunnable15756 implements Runnable
{
    String s1 = "Hello World";
    String s2 = "Hello New World";
    Runnable runnable1 =  new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
              synchronized(s1)
                {
                    for(int i =0;i<30;++i)
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+s1);

                }

        }
    };

    Runnable runnable2 =  new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
             synchronized(s2)
                {
                    for(int i = 0;i<30;++i)
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+s2);
                }

        }
    };
    public void run()
    {

        new Thread(runnable1).start();

        new Thread(runnable2).start();



    }
}
```

Comment: in this way you can achieve what you have mentioned.